# How to use a custom predicate sort with Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like `[[1,2,"s"],[1,5,"e"],...]` where the 3rd value is always either `s` or `e`. How can I call `sort()` such that the list is sorted based on:

1. the first index
2. if the first index is same, `s` comes first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom `key` function.

```
def sort_key(list_):
    if list_[2] == 's':
        return (list_[0], 0)
    return (list_[0], 1)

test_list = [[1, 2, 's'], [1, 5, 'e'], [2, 4, 'e'], [2, 3, 's']]
test_list.sort(key=sort_key)
# [[1, 2, 's'], [1, 5, 'e'], [2, 3, 's'], [2, 4, 'e']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass custom key function to [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) that is used to generate the comparison key for the items:

```
>>> l = [[1, 5, 'e'], [1, 2, 's'], [0, 4, 'e']]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -ord(x[2])))
>>> l
[[0, 4, 'e'], [1, 2, 's'], [1, 5, 'e']]
```