# How do I rearrange my Numpy array by a specific sequence?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to rearrange the following Numpy array:

```
X = [ 1.  5.  2.  4.  2.  4.  1.  5.  2.  1.  2.  1.  5.  6.  2.  6.  5.  4.
  3.  1.  4.  6.  5.  3.  1.  5.  4.  5.  3.  3.  1.  4.  4.  5.  4.  4.
  3.  6.  1.  5.  4.  1.  4.  4.  1.  5.  1.  2.  1.  4.  6.  1.  3.  4.
  1.  6.  3.  1.  1.  5.  6.  4.  5.  2.  6.  3.  1.  3.  4.  6.  3.  2.
  1.  4.  2.  4.  2.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  6.  4.  3.  6.  1.  1.  4.  1.
  4.  4. nan nan nan nan]
```

by the following sequence `3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1`.

Essentially, the entire array is arranged such that all the 3's come first, 2's, 6's, 5's, 4's and finally 1's. What is the best way to do this, while retaining the Numpy array instead of turning it into a list?

Comment: is it coma or dot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort numpy array with custom predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799335/sort-numpy-array-with-custom-predicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `list.index`:

```
ind = [3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1]
sorted(X, key=lambda x : ind.index(x) if x in ind else -1)
```

Output:

```
[nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 3,
 ...
 1,
 1,
 1]
```

If you want `nan` to come at last:

```
last = len(ind)
sorted(X, key=lambda x : ind.index(x) if x in ind else last)
```

Output:

```
[3,
 3,
 ...
 1,
 1,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan]
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you! Is there a way of retaining the object type such that it is a numpy array rather than a list?

Comment: @MichikoC You can always wrap `sorted(...)` with `np.array`: `np.array(sorted(X, key = ...))`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it seems that key can't be something like ind = [3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1] though?

Comment: You mean without using `lambda`? No you need to use `ind` inside of `lambda` just like in the answer ;)

Comment: Oh! I apologize - I meant, I tried using np.array(sorted(X, key = ...)) but it seems key can't be something like key = ind.

Comment: @MichikoC I'm afraid you can't use `ind` directly as your `key` for `sorted`. `key` must be a callable of some sort, and `list` is not a one.