# Change location of string in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array that contains strings.

```
index1 = ['level4','level3','level2','UNKNOWN','level1']
```

I want to arrange this numpy array such that `'UNKNOWN'` is always the first string in the array.

Desired array:

```
index1 = ['UNKNOWN','level4','level3','level2','level1']
```

Sorting of level is not desirable

Comment: You also sort the levels. Is this desired?

Comment: No, sorting of level is not desirable.

Comment: Do you want to sort lists or numpy arrays? The code you show in the question creates a list.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487543/3005167 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45799487/3005167 answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

## Simplest answer

If you literally just want `'UNKNOWN'` to be in front, then the easiest and most computationally efficient way to do so is to just swap it with the `0`th element:

```
index1 = np.array(['level4','level3','level2','UNKNOWN','level1'])
# find the index of 'UNKNOWN'
ix = np.flatnonzero(index1 == 'UNKNOWN')[0]
# swap values
index1[[0, ix]] = index1[[ix, 0]]

print(index1)
# output:
#    ['UNKNOWN' 'level3' 'level2' 'level4' 'level1']
```

## Preserve the original order of the `level` elements

If you want the `level` elements to have the same order in the output as in the input, here's a (slightly more complicated but still pretty simple) way to make that happen:

```
index1 = np.array(['level4','level3','level2','UNKNOWN','level1'])
# find the index of 'UNKNOWN'
ix = np.flatnonzero(index1 == 'UNKNOWN')[0]
# shift values
u = index1[ix]
index1[1:ix + 1] = index1[:ix]
index1[0] = u

print(index1)
# output:
#    ['UNKNOWN' 'level4' 'level3' 'level2' 'level1']
```

## Don't use `partition`

If you don't want the results to be sorted, then you shouldn't use [`numpy.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy-partition):

```
index1 = np.array(['level4','level3','level2','UNKNOWN','level1'])
index1.partition(np.flatnonzero(index1 == 'UNKNOWN'))

print(index1)
# output:
#     ['UNKNOWN' 'level1' 'level2' 'level3' 'level4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.roll`:

```
import numpy as np

index1 = np.array(['level4','level3','level2','UNKNOWN','level1'])

position = np.where(index1 == 'UNKNOWN')[0][0]
index1[:position + 1] = np.roll(index1[:position + 1], 1)
print(index1)
```

---

```
array(['UNKNOWN', 'level4', 'level3', 'level2', 'level1'], dtype='<U7')
```

Comment: This does not preserve the order of the other elements

Comment: @anishtain4 What exactly do you mean? The original order of the `level` elements was `(4, 3, 2, 1)`, which is the same order that the `level` elements have in Tomothy's output.

Answer (score 0):

partition() will permit to reorder your array, but will be sorted.

```
index1.partition(np.where(index1=='UNKNOWN')[0][0])
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Took me a second, but then I realized that the use of `partition` doesn't answer the question. The result will be sorted.